# Yield an item with Python Bottle doesn't work

Tags: python, iterator, generator, python-2.x, yield

When using:

```
from bottle import route, run, request, view

N = 0

def yielditem():
    global N
    for i in range(100):
        N = i
        yield i

@route('/')
@view('index.html')
def index():
    print yielditem()
    print N    

run(host='localhost', port=80, debug=False)
```

the page `index.html` is successfully displayed, but the `yield` part is not working:

- `N` stays always at 0, for every new request
- `print yielditem()` gives `<generator object yielditem at 0x0000000002D40EE8>`

**How to make this `yield` work normally in this Bottle Python context?**

What I expect is: `0` should be printed at the first request, `1` should be printed at the second request, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are printing the generator itself not its values:

```
from bottle import route, run, request, view

N = 0
def yielditem():
    global N
    for i in range(100):
        N = i
        yield i

yf = yielditem()

@route('/')
@view('index.html')
def index():
    print next(yf)
    print N    

run(host='localhost', port=80, debug=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't have *anything* to do with Bottle, it's solely about the generator function.

When you call `yielditem()`, you get, as Python tells you, a *generator object* `yielditem`. It doesn't magically start iterating over it.

If you do want to iterate over the generator object, you must do this explicitly, with something like `print(next(yielditem()))`.

How you want to *use* that generator is another story: if you want to access the same generator object during multiple function calls, you can place it outside the function called:

```
generator_object = yielditem()

def print_it():  # this is like your `index` function
    print "Current value: {}".format(next(generator_object))

for x in range(10):  # this is like a client reloading the page
    print_it()
```